# Visual C# Combobox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Hello does anyone here know how to set a default value for A combo box?
By the way I'm using microsoft visual studio 2010.
I can't find any option in the properties tab. :((

Do you know any site which offers comprehensive tutorial about visual studio 2010? This software is really killing me...

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms, WPF, or what?

Comment: @John: I've noticed that when someone doesn't know which UI framework they're using, or just refers to it as "C#", it's usually WinForms ;)

Answer (score 1):

All may work.

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0; // what ever index you want
comboBox1.Text = "String"; // what ever index you want
comboBox1.SelectedValue = obj; // an objet value
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "default value" property, but you can set the selected value in the `Load` event:

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedValue = ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) property. To set the combobox to the first item in your collection you would write.

```
Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: Can I just have a follow up question here? or should I post a new topic??

Comment: @warook you should mark THE answer as answer and then post another separate question.

Comment: @warook If you agree with the answer I posted, it would be the appropriate thing to do to mark my answer as correct. Also, feel free to ask another question here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
    ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Value A", "Value B"})
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

This will show Value A as the default selected value for a combobox

Any value above 0 will work, the default value for SelectedIndex is -1 which means that no value is shown, so you have to use anything above 0, depending on what value you need to show.